# Highstock disappearing on after navigation and does not show x axis on full range

Tags: highcharts

When I select full range, y axis disappears. And if I navigate anywhere other than full range, chart disappears.

Comment: code link- http://jsfiddle.net/en5vjdLu/

Comment: you data needs to be sorted by the x axis, in you case by the date http://jsfiddle.net/en5vjdLu/2/